# Can not start etcd cluster when setting up a HA K8S cluster

Tags: firewall, kubernetes, cluster, high-availability

I am following this article to set up a HA k8s cluster:
[Guide: Kubernetes Multi-Master HA Cluster with kubeadm](https://tansanrao.com/kubernetes-ha-cluster-with-kubeadm/)

I have three master nodes(3,4,5) and four worker nodes(2,6,7,8) (one of the worker nodes is HAProxy Load Balancer)

In "Installing and configuring Etcd on all 3 Master Nodes" section, step6,  I get the following error in master node 3:

```
{"level":"warn","ts":"2023-03-28T17:21:07.929-0700","caller":"clientv3/retry_interceptor.go:62","msg":"retrying of unary invoker failed","target":"endpoint://client-beafcd7b-fbf5-4c3e-b9ce-5c1032e26041/127.0.0.1:2379","attempt":0,"error":"rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded"}
Error: context deadline exceeded
```

However, in other master nodes(4 and 5), I get the following:

```
162974ed2b5b12b2, started, 192.168.60.4, https://192.168.60.4:2380, https://192.168.60.4:2379, false
5642d9d9da8c08a3, started, 192.168.60.3, https://192.168.60.3:2380, https://192.168.60.3:2379, false
6ffc3bfbd773170f, started, 192.168.60.5, https://192.168.60.5:2380, https://192.168.60.5:2379, false
```

here is etcd.service for node 3:

```
[Unit]
Description=etcd
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos


[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \
  --name 192.168.60.3 \
  --cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem \
  --key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --peer-cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem \
  --peer-key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --trusted-ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.pem \
  --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.pem \
  --peer-client-cert-auth \
  --client-cert-auth \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://192.168.60.3:2380 \
  --listen-peer-urls https://192.168.60.3:2380 \
  --listen-client-urls https://192.168.60.3:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls https://192.168.60.3:2379 \
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-0 \
  --initial-cluster 192.168.60.3=https://192.168.60.3:2380,192.168.60.4=https://192.168.60.4:2380,192.168.60.5=https://192.168.60.5:2380 \
  --initial-cluster-state new \
  --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

etcd.service for node 4:

```
[Unit]
Description=etcd
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos


[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \
  --name 192.168.60.4 \
  --cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem \
  --key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --peer-cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem \
  --peer-key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --trusted-ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.pem \
  --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.pem \
  --peer-client-cert-auth \
  --client-cert-auth \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://192.168.60.4:2380 \
  --listen-peer-urls https://192.168.60.4:2380 \
  --listen-client-urls https://192.168.60.4:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls https://192.168.60.4:2379 \
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-0 \
  --initial-cluster 192.168.60.3=https://192.168.60.3:2380,192.168.60.4=https://192.168.60.4:2380,192.168.60.5=https://192.168.60.5:2380 \
  --initial-cluster-state new \
  --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

etcd.service for node 5:

```
[Unit]
Description=etcd
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos


[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \
  --name 192.168.60.5 \
  --cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem \
  --key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --peer-cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem \
  --peer-key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --trusted-ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.pem \
  --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.pem \
  --peer-client-cert-auth \
  --client-cert-auth \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls https://192.168.60.5:2380 \
  --listen-peer-urls https://192.168.60.5:2380 \
  --listen-client-urls https://192.168.60.5:2379,http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls https://192.168.60.5:2379 \
  --initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-0 \
  --initial-cluster 192.168.60.3=https://192.168.60.3:2380,192.168.60.4=https://192.168.60.4:2380,192.168.60.5=https://192.168.60.5:2380 \
  --initial-cluster-state new \
  --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5



[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

if I use :

```
 ETCDCTL_API=2 etcdctl member list
```

I can get :

```
client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: client: endpoint http://127.0.0.1:2379 exceeded header timeout
; error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connect: connection refused
```